# mapping a range of dates to time slots with reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class `TimeSlotEntity` and I have a range object with dates, that's, roughly speaking, is like this:

```
const slotRange = ['15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00'];
```

In code it looks like this:

```
const range = moments.range(startEventTime, endEventTime).by('minutes', { step: 30 });
```

The `TimeSlotEntity` class has date setters: `setDateFrom(val: Moment)`, `setDateTo(val: Moment)`;

I would like to map the range to the corresponding `TimeSlotEntity`s so that the first slot would be from 15:00 to 15:30, the second one from 15:30 to 16:00, the third one from 16:00 to 16:30 etc.

How to do this with the javascript reduce function?

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked specifically to use `reduce`, but I'd still just go with good old `for` loops.

```
const rangesArray = Array.from(ranges);

const timeSlotEntities = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rangesArray.length - 1; i++) {
  const timeSlotEntity = new TimeSlotEntity();

  timeSlotEntity.setDateFrom(rangesArray[i]);
  timeSlotEntity.setDateTo(rangesArray[i + 1]);

  timeSlotEntities.push(timeSlotEntity);
}
```

It would only work if the `ranges` array contains at least two elements.

If `TimeSlotEntity` can have an `undefined` end date, then you can modify the loop condition to `i < ranges.length` and that would work with `ranges` with only one element.

Comment: haha well yeah it was my first solution but I decided to `reduce` it to something less verbose but couldn't do this in a concise way...so decided to ask here. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Albert you must show what you tried before :)

Comment: @MaximeGirou What do you mean? What I've tried is not what I'm looking for. I tried a number of solutions, I'm not satisfied with them, that's why I'm here asking this question. What is the point of posting that stuff?